# Finding the accelerations of objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I want to know how to get the accelerations separately in each object

[image]

Comment: People would like to see you analysis, what you have tried and failed. The site is about helping with solution, not making solution for you. Seeing some own effort is required. Questions looking like "Do my homework for me" can be rejected.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

F=ma where F is the sum of forces.  The top block has a 12 N force to the right, and a force to the left caused by friction.  It does depend on how the coeficient is defined, but I  imagine the force is the downward force*0.2, so 2kg*9.81 m/s*.2 = 3.9 N.  So the net force on the top block is 12-3.9 = 8.1 N, and acceleration is F/m.

Then you would repeat for the next block which has a net force on top of 3.9 N to the right.  If its friction force is greater than 3.9, then the two lower blocks move as one over the smooth bottom surface (no friction if I understand the problem correctly).

Comment: Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.